# Какой тип данных написать что бы вернуть массив строк

Tags: c++, типы, split

Какой тип должен стоять у функции что бы она вернула массив строк.

Класс

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

class Fun {
public:
    Split(std::string text, std::string separator) {
        int i = 0;
        std::regex regex("\\"+separator);
    
        std::vector<std::string> out(
                        std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), regex, -1),
                        std::sregex_token_iterator()
                        );
    
        for (auto &s: out) {
            i++;
        }
        std::string res_arr[i] ;
        i=0;
        for (auto &s: out) {
            res_arr[i] = s;
            i++;
        }
        return res_arr;
    }
};
```

вызов:

```
Fun testclass;
result = Fun.Split("Текст который хочу ! разделить","!");
```

p.s. Не судите строго за авнокод, только неделю учу плюсы.

Comment: Никакой. В С++ отсутствует возможность возвращать массивы. Кроме того, этот код невалидный, так как размер массива должен быть константой времени компиляции. Используйте `::std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что объявление массива с размером, известным во время выполнения — действие не стандартное, это расширение компилятора GCC. Так что

```
std::string res_arr[i] ;
```

в этом смысле — соответствия стандарту — не работает. Но если бы и работало — то при возврате массива возвращается указатель на его первый элемент, сам массив не копируется. Но это указатель на *локальную* переменную, которая исчезнет при выходе из функции и остаетесь вы у разбитого корыта...

Можно создать массив динамически:

```
string * res_arr = new string[i];
```

и вернуть `res_arr`. Функция при этом имеет вид

```
string * Split(std::string text, std::string separator)
```

Внутри функции с `res_arr` вы работаете так же, как с массивом. Это сработает. Но есть пару "но": по указателю неизвестен размер массива, а значит, его надо передавать отдельно, и теперь вы отвечаете за освобождение выделенной памяти.

Есть интересное решение — "завернуть" массив в структуру, что-то вроде

```
struct Ret
{
    string res_arr[i]; // Или string * res_arr
    int res_arr_size;
};
```

Так можно убить двух зайцев: во-первых, структура при возврате копируется, так что пропадает проблема с локальной переменной, а во-вторых, вы возвращаете заодно и размер массива.

Но это, по сути, изобретение велосипеда, так как такая (вернее, куда более мощная) структура давно есть в С++ — это `vector`.

Так что лучше всего объявить

```
std::vector<std::string> Split(std::string text, std::string separator)
```

(а еще лучше

```
std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string& text, const std::string& separator)
```

чтобы не копировать большие строки), а в функции написать

```
std::vector<std::string> res_arr(i);
```

и работать точно так же. Но поскольку вектор — это больше, чем просто структура, вам даже не надо делать предварительный проход для выяснения количества элементов — можно сразу же *добавлять* элементы в вектор. Он сам разберется с выделением памяти. Так вы не имеете проблемы с локальной переменной, не меняете синтаксис обращения к элементам, всегда знаете количество элементов в векторе (для чего используется функция `.size()`) — одни плюсы. Небольшой минус — немного лишней памяти, но, как правило, она невелика, да и ту можно уменьшить — в вашем случае таки определяя, сколько элементов будет в векторе, заранее.